# SimplePie- How do I filter feed items that dont have images?

Tags: php, parsing, rss, simplepie, rss-reader

I only want feed items that have images. How do I filter out the ones that don't?

Answer (score 1):

In your loop through the items, you can check the item content for the img tag:

```
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $key=>$item) {
   if ( stristr($item->get_content(), '<img') == false ) {
      // show the article
   }
}
```

This code will only show articles that DON'T have images. To do the opposite, change the condition:

```
if ( stristr($item->get_content(), '<img') != false ) {
```

Comment: Would it be possible to do the same with to only parse feeds that are a minimum of x width? Ex. If the image in the feed is less than 300 pixels wide, filter it out.

Comment: That would be a lot tougher since many img tags do not contain the width or height. You would likely have to pull the source image and use PHP's Imagick functions to get the width. That would be tons of work for not much gain.